# Will U.S. Customs at international airports be discreet when asking me about previous criminal charges?

Tags: visas, usa, legal

I'm an F1 student visa. I was arrested in 2012 for a misdemeanor (soliciting a prostitute) when I was completing my MA. This incident, which I still regret it very much to this moment, has been dropped by the court after I did 40 hours of community services in 2013. Note, after that incident, I returned back to my country for a vacation and returned back to the U.S. in Washington airport. The US Customs at that time transferred me to a secluded big hall. And another officer, after waiting two hours, asked me about this incident. And I answered him truthfully. He allowed me to check in the US border. This was after I finished my community services and before the case was dropped.

When I applied for another F1 visa for my PhD studies I was refused (under 214b section) at first, but after a long battle with embassy consulate officer I finally convinced them and I got approved.

My concern is I got married and my wife has no idea about this incident and I'm afraid that an officer might ask me the same question in front of her about this incident cause I love my wife so much and I don't want to lose her.

Do you think I'm going to be asked this question if I come to the US? And if yes, can anyone suggest something so I can protect my marriage?

Comment: You have the same issue as what? In any case, it sounds like you're probably trying to come to the US as a student? If so, you need Expatriates.SE, not Travel.SE.

Comment: @Flimzy it's more about the us border questions as a traveller, not sure the type of visa matters - it's more if they're going to ask him about his misdemeanor

Comment: I assume you meant “soliciting a prostitute”. @Flimzy Basically the OP isn't really concerned about being able to enter, expatriation or anything like that but about the whole incident being revealed to his wife during routine questioning at the US border.

Comment: This question is much more about marital counselling than it is about travel.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion. To clarify, are the U.S. Borders going to ask me in the airports (for example JFK)  about the incident that took place in 2012 (soliciting a prostitute) even though I got approved by the US embassy yesterday? And I apologize I'm a new user in this website.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Ah I see. It makes more sense now that you've spelled it out. Can we clean up the question to ask just that, without all the tangential information?

Comment: I don't think we do relationship advice here, but I'd probably just tell her what happened. It'll be less embarrassing.

Comment: What jamessug said. Also, does your wife use the internet? Might she Google your name?

Comment: Hey Jamessug, I thing you didn't understand my question. Leave the relationship aside and concentrate on the first part of the question. here it is again, Are the U.S. Borders going to ask me in the airports check in (for example JFK) about the incident that took place in 2012 (soliciting a prostitute) even though I got approved by the US embassy yesterday? I'll be more than happy to draw it to you and make it more clearer.

Comment: I cannot source this answer for you, so it's only a comment, but I would think that yes, they will continue to ask you about it. The real question is if you are questioned in private, and/or can ask to be so, also will doing so cause your wife concern as to why?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to clean drug misdemeanor in US so I don't get stopped at border every time?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45547/3221) Though, to save your marriage, your wife should know about this.

Comment: @Hope25 I'd consider editing your question to remove a lot of the specifics. You're basically asking if immigration will be discrete when asking about a previous misdemeanor if you're travelling with your spouse. The general question is perfectly on topic and would avoid the extended discussion. Although, for what it's worth, you should just tell your wife. We all did stuff we're not proud of long ago, she did too I'm sure, it'll be hard but it's not going to be a relationship-breaker (but you are cautioned about taking relationship advice from people pretending to be dogs on the internet).

Answer (score 9):

This may be difficult. Your record is probably flagged by immigration and likely to pop up when the first level immigration officer scans your visa. It's in the discretion of the office how to proceed but it's not unlikely that she/he will ask you about it or, even worse, send you to secondary inspection.

I used to go to secondary inspection a lot because I was on a status that was called "Advanced Parole" (not kidding). It is not a nice place. I have seen some fairly disturbing things there and the word "discreet" does not rank very highly in the vocabulary of the officers working there.

The chances that you can get into the US without this coming up are fairly low.